# Is there any way to store results of a stored procedure run and add that in next result

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on an HR Leaves Approval Module.

I'm passing a date range to a stored procedure and it returns as results the approved leaves within that date range.

Now when I a enter new date range, I want results with previous range one too.

I tried to store result of the query in another table in the database, but I only get the last results.

I just want the most recent previous results to be added to the results of the next run.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please post the code that you tried. Are you saying that the SP returns multiple result sets? I don't think there is a way in T-SQL to get anything other than the last result set.

Comment: And sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can store the output of SP inside a temporary table using `INSERT INTO` like following

```
INSERT INTO #tmp
Exec YourSP <Parameters>
```

Now you can use the temp table for the remaining queries.